# How do I copy multiple files from multiple hosts in powershell?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to make a powershell script (5.1) that will copy several files and folders from several hosts, these hosts change frequently therefore it would be  ideal if I can use a list that I can append when required.

I have this all working using xcopy so I know the locations exist. I want to ensure that if a change is made when I am not In work someone can just add or remove a host in the text file and the back up will continue to work.

The code I have is supposed to go through each host in my list of hosts and copy all the files from the list of file paths before moving onto the next host.

But there are 2 errors showing up:

> The term '\REMOTEHOST\c$\Users\Public\desktop\back-up\$Computers' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script 
>   file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
>   At line:8 char:17

and:

> copy-item : Cannot find path '\HOST\C$\LK\Appdata\Cmmcfg  C$\LKAppData\Errc  C$\LK\Appdata\TCOMP  C$\LK\Probes  C$\LK\Appdata\CAMIO  C$\LK\Appdata\LaunchPad  C$\LK\Appdata\Wincmes 
>   C$\barlen.dta  C$\Caliprogs  C$\Cali' because it does not exist.

This does not seem to reading through the list as I intended, I have also noticed that the HOST it is reading from is 6th in the list and not first.

```
REM*This file contains the list of hosts you want to copy files from*
    $computers = Get-Content 'Y:\***FILEPATH***\HOSTFILE.txt'

REM*This is the file/folder(s) you want to copy from the hosts in the $computer variable*
    $source = Get-Content 'Y:\***FILEPATH***\FilePaths.txt'

REM*The destination location you want the file/folder(s) to be copied to*
    $destination = \\**REMOTEHOST**\c$\Users\Public\desktop\back-up\$Computers

    foreach ($item in $computers) {

    }  

    foreach ($item in $source) {

    }

    copy-item \\$computer\$source -Destination $destination -Verbose
```

Comment: REM is for batch or basic, comments in PowerShell have a `#` in front.

Comment: Hi In my code it does, however when I was importing it the format went to a large font and bold so I removed them to try and make it a bit easier on the eye.

Answer (score 0):

Your destination variable needs to be enclosed in quotes. To have it evaluate other variables inside of it, enclose it in double quotes. Otherwise PowerShell thinks it's a command you are trying to run.

```
$destination = "\\**REMOTEHOST**\c$\Users\Public\desktop\back-up\$Computers"
```

Comment: Hi There! thank you very much! That has almost got it! do you happen to know how I make it move through one item at once? I am now getting an error which says it cannot find host 1, host 2, host 3..... and is just listing the contents of the text file

Comment: I don't know what the directory or file structures are, but you may need to nest your foreach loops.

    foreach ($computer in $computers) {
        $destination = "\\**REMOTEHOST**\c$\Users\Public\desktop\back-up\$Computer"
        foreach ($source in $sources) {
            copy-item "\\$computer\$source" -Destination $destination -Verbos
        }
    }

Comment: Hi Thank you for your response, sorry its vague I am not allowed to post all the details because of work, nesting my foreach loop has not worked, it has removed all the errors and stopped the script from just cycling through the list but its still not copying the files. Thanks for the help though one more step forward :)

Comment: Just an update, I have edited the text file to contain a single host and single file path and it does work, it is only when using multiple hosts or file paths that there is an error. I think it is because the powershell script is reading the whole file instead of line by line

Answer (score 0):

cracked it, thank you for your help. I was messing up the foreach command!I had both variables set to Item, so I was confusing things!

foreach ($itemhost in $computers) {
 $destination = "\Remotehost\c$\Users\xoliver.jeffries\desktop\back-up\$itemhost" 
 foreach ($item in $source)
 {copy-item "\$itemhost\$item*" -Destination $destination -Verbose -recurse} 
 }

Its not the neatest output but that's just a snag! the code now enables me to use a list of hosts and a list files and copy them to a remote server!